# Check whether property has minimum number of characters (or contains a space) in WIX

Tags: wix

I'm attempting to verify a user's input in a MaskedEdit control to ensure that it contains the 10 numeric chars (for a phone number). How can I apply such a condition?

My current code only checks to see whether the property is empty.

```
<Publish Dialog="InstitInfoDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InstitInfoDlgError" Order="1">((INSTITUTIONNAME = "") OR (INSTITUTIONTEL = "")) OR (INSTITUTIONTEL = "   -   -    ")</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstitInfoDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="2">(NOT (INSTITUTIONNAME = "") AND NOT (INSTITUTIONTEL = "")) AND NOT (INSTITUTIONTEL = "   -   -    ")</Publish>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Windows installer [Conditional Statement Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) docs, what you require is not possible.

Your can either use the [Regex_Match](http://dblock.github.io/msiext/docs/1.3/_string_tools_impl_8h.html#a471c59d73e8b0b14c761111a095d9ce4) custom action in the [MsiExt](http://dblock.github.io/msiext/) custom actions or you can create a custom action yourself to do the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [substring operators](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/com-expression-syntax-miscellanea/expression-syntax) to check if the string contains a space.

```
INSTITUTIONTEL >< " "
```

Note that, since this includes angle brackets, you'll need to include the whole expression in a CDATA section.

```
<Publish Dialog="InstitInfoDlg" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="InstitInfoDlgError" Order="1"><![CDATA[((INSTITUTIONNAME = "") OR (INSTITUTIONTEL = "")) OR (INSTITUTIONTEL >< " ")]]></Publish>
<Publish Dialog="InstitInfoDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="2"><![CDATA[(NOT (INSTITUTIONNAME = "") AND NOT (INSTITUTIONTEL = "")) AND NOT (INSTITUTIONTEL >< " ")]]></Publish>
```